# how to moving object twice from list to another list and set object variable differently

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have question about assigning object to arraylist with nearly same objects, the objects come from another list which I want to add to the arraylist two times, and before I add it to another list, I need to set value a variable in those objects.

this the code,

```
ArrayList<ClassCourse> courses = new ArrayList<ClassCourse>();
ArrayList<ClassCourse> _courses = new ArrayList<ClassCourse>();

int index = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++ )
{
    ClassCourse t = courses.get(i);
    if(t.getSks()==4)      
    {
        i--;
        t.setSks(2);
        t.setIndex(index); // I want to set this one
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        t.setIndex(index); // I want to set this one
        index++;
    }
    _courses.add(t);
}
```

the problem is when I check the list by print it

```
for( ClassCourse t : _courses )
    System.out.println( t.getIndex() + " " + t.getName() + " " +
            t.getCourseCode() + " " + t.getSks() );
```

and this is what I get

```
1 Visi Komputer A 2
1 Visi Komputer A 2
2 Matematika Diskrit C 3
4 Jaringan Nirkabel dan Komputasi Bergerak A 2
4 Jaringan Nirkabel dan Komputasi Bergerak A 2
5 Pemograman Framework .NET A 3
6 Perancangan dan Analisis Algoritma E 3
8 Sistem Terdistribusi A 2
8 Sistem Terdistribusi A 2
9 Matematika Diskrit D 3
11 Manajemen Proyek Perangkat Lunak A 2
11 Manajemen Proyek Perangkat Lunak A 2
```

I can't get index's value increasing in right way

Comment: is _courses an empty list or it has same calue as courses? I can see multiple entries in the output

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(t.getSks()==4)      
{
    i--;
    t.setSks(2);
    t.setIndex(index); // I want to set this one
    index++;
}
```

I guess you are decrementing i so that the object is added twice. But remember that its the same object that's getting added to the list. So when you set t.setIndex(index) it will change the value of index for the previous iteration.
This is because java deals with references only. So courses.get(0) and courses.get(1) returns a reference to the same object and hence this behaviour.
If you want the index to be different then you may need to clone the object and add it again to the list. You will need to think thru this and decide if you want another copy of the object or not.